# If two points, $x$ and $y$, are on a line $AB$ and $AX >BY$ then is it true that $AY + BX > BY$?

Tags: geometry

So the answers say that its $D$ ($AY > BX$) but no matter what I try I can't prove $C$ ($AY + BX > AB$) wrong. Can anyone help me understand how $C$ is wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following counterexample:

[image: Counterexample]

Here $AX>BY,$ but since $AY$ and $BX$ are small relative to $BY,$ your proposed inequality fails.